# Why map control is not appearing in windows mobile 6

Tags: asp.net

I developed one asp.net web site with functionality of finding route, find place 
through bing map control.

My Problem is when I am opening this web site from windows mobile with internet explorer 6.

**All controls are appearing but map control is not appearing why?**

```
<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2&mkt=en-us">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function OnPageLoad()
{  
    var myMap = document.getElementById("myMap");

    var LA = new VELatLong(41.2666452, -96.0011320,VELatLong.RelativeToGround);

    myMap.style.display='';
    map = new VEMap('myMap');
    map.LoadMap(LA, 1, VEMapStyle.Road, false, VEMapMode.Mode2D, true, 1);
}
</script>
```

can any one help me?

Thanks

Comment: You have said that my answer to your previous question solved your problem. Then could you please mark the answer as accepted? Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747729/how-to-convert-non-exponential-numbers-to-exponential-number-in-c/1747767#1747767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing IE Mobile, I'd say it's something to do with your JavaScript probably.

How are you showing the map? Posting some code to your question would certainly help people narrow down the issue.

Looking at the directions service from bing.com on IE mobile, the map is a static image with the directions rendered on top - is this what you're doing? Or are you trying to call the default js map controls?

---

Edit to respond to update:

If you take a look at [bing mobile](http://m.bing.com/search/) you'll see that they aren't using the fully featured client side API, but are doing the bulk of the lifting on the server, culminating in a simple img tag being sent to the mobile browser to generate a static image request.

This sort of process is also talked about in this article on "[Getting a map with the Virtual Earth Web Service](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/blogs/maps/archive/2008/09/26/getting-a-map-with-the-virtual-earth-web-service.aspx)", which concludes:

> VEWS provides static images (on the fly), so you can insert them anywhere that support HTTP requests - *mobile devices*, JavaScript disabled browsers - or insert them into other documents such as PDFs.

Comment: Is there any other way to show map control in windows mobile?
Thank for u r valuable reply.

Comment: The problem you'll have is that IE Mobile still has fairly poor JavaScript support, so you need to work around that - and the best way to do that is to  The latest versions of Opera Mobile are quite good, so there is hope.