# How to convert non-Exponential numbers to Exponential number in c#

Tags: c#

we have some calculation in our project like convertion from non-Exponential("1234567890.1234567890" numbers to Exponential("1.234567890E+10") number.

is there any solution for above issue?

please help me to come out from this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you need to use [Double.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/7yd1h1be%28VS.80%29.aspx) (if you have the number as a string) and then [Double.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) with the appropriate [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). For example: `number.ToString("E")`

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
string.Format("{0:#.0#E-00}", NumericValue);
```

or

```
string.Format("{0:E}", NumericValue);
```